# How can I include the Weka API javadoc in Netbeans (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, ubuntu, javadoc, weka

I am currently using Ubuntu as my OS.
I need to include the Weka API javadoc in my Netbeans IDE installation.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the steps of adding Weka API Javadoc to NetBeans IDE:

1. Right click on the project -> Properties -> Libraries
2. Select the library to which you want to add javadoc
3. Click the Edit button and from there you can Browse javadoc folder.

The Javadoc folder of Weka is in the installation directory of Weka-X-X (i.e `~/Weka-3-6`).

Comment: Has this changed? I'm on Weka 3.8 and I don't see any javadoc in that folder or any subfolder. Some classes seem to have docs by default but others like Weka.core.Instances methods don't.

Comment: @Hack-R: I also have the same problem as you do. Can't find javadoc anywhere :(. It seems that the Weka team has decided to store the documentation in .html form. You can find it in ~/Weka/documentation.html, it works just like the online version. All the docs are stored in ~/Weka/doc/ folder. IMHO this seems unnecessarily complicated, why don't they just include a javadoc ? .....

Comment: @Hack-R turns out that in Netbeans, you can add the .html doc just fine as you would add a simple .javadoc. Just select Libraries (inside your project) -> add JAR/folder then choose ~/Weka/doc/.